# How can I stop a button from stealing my keypress event?

Tags: c#, events, button, keypress

I have a button that keeps stealing my keypress event. How do I override this? I want to have a method run when enter is clicked when the focus is on the form, but the button steals it.

Comment: Is the button default?  Look for the `AcceptButton` property on the form.

Comment: the AcceptButton is set to none

Comment: You're probably registering `button.Click` event which would steal `Enter` presses. You should use `button.MouseClick` or something similar.

Comment: nawful: this helped with the button stealing the keypress event but now the keypress doesn't run the mehtod i want it to run at all.

Comment: @user2452737 I do not know what you mean. You mean your keypress eventhandler is not called? Try keydown or something then. And kindly tag my name as "@ nawfal" (without the space, as I did u), only then i'm notified.

Answer (score 0):

Handle the KeyDown event in the Form:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(Object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.KeyCode & Keys.Enter) == Keys.Enter)
    {
        //do something
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    else
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Buttons` do **not** steal the `KeyPress` event, they 'only' steal the `Enter` key. So you can do something like this:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
    {
        processYourKey( keyData);
        return false;                 // do not steal!
    }
    processYourKey( keyData);
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```